# touchesBegan ignored in subclass of uiresponder

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiresponder

working on an ios app with objective c and using xcode. I have a class that inherits from another class that inherits from UIResponder and it contains a view. I have a touchesBegan within the sub class but the event only gets called when running the app in debug/dev mode. when i make a production/release build the touch event is not getting called.

```
// Basic viewcontroller protocol
@protocol SubViewController
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
    - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated;
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated;
    - (void)viewDidLoad;
    -(UIView *)view;
@end


@interface SubViewController : UIResponder<SubViewController> {
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// A custom subview controller
//

@interface mySubViewController : SubViewController {

}
```

and within mysubviewcontroller class i have

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   //some code and magic
}
```

Now as i said running this in debug is fine but the touch event is ignored in release. any tips, ideas or questions to help clarify this for you please say. thanks in advance

edit: i seen this in the doc "If you override this method without calling super (a common use pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch events, if only as stub (empy) implementations." so i stubbed in all the other touch events but no change on release build

Comment: Any particular reason you're not subclassing `UIViewController` (which already inherits from `UIResponder`)? I suspect your custom `UIResponder` subclass isn't added to the responder chain properly.

Comment: hmm how do i check if the subclass is added to responder chain? or what is the correct way to add it? im sure there was a reason for not subclassing uiviewcontroller but cant for the life of me think of it now and was wrote a long time ago.

Comment: See the 3rd paragraph in the [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs. Basically, you'd need to override `nextResponder` in the view that you're managing and your "view controller". The view would return the view controller and the view controller would return the view's superview.

Comment: k ill give this a shot and get back to u. any ideas why it would work while debugging though?

Comment: that did it cheers. some weird things were going on there. now part of responder chain. u want to do that as an answer or so i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're not subclassing `UIViewController` (which does this automatically), you need to add your responder to the responder chain manually.

A `UIViewController`'s position in the responder chain is between its view and the view's superview, so to get the same behavior, you need to override `nextResponder` in both your view and the controller that manages it. The view should return the controller and the controller should return the view's superview.